# jQuery access parent but object is null?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the parent of a selected option which is a td and then use insertAfter to insert another td after it but the reference is coming back null? Can someone tell me why?

Thanks

```
JQ('.defieldselect').live('change',function(){
    var $option = JQ(this).find('option:selected');
    if($option.attr('rel')=='Date'){            
        var ddlID = $option.parent().parent().parent().find('.criteria-value').find('input').attr("id");
        var index = ddlID.split("_")[1];
        var select = CreateDateSelectList(index);
        $(select).insertAfter($option.parent);
    }        
});
```

HTML

```
    <tr>

        <td id="g1_c0_criteria_field" class="criteria-field">
            <select class="defieldselect" name="g1_c0_criteria_field">

<option rel="Text">Product ID 1</option>
<option rel="Date">Date Added</option>

            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="criteria-operator">
            <select id="g1_c0_criteria_operator" name="g1_c0_criteria_operator">
                <option value="=">is equal to</option>
                <option value="!=">is not equal to</option>
                <option value="&gt;">is greater than</option>
                <option value="&lt;">is less than</option>
                <option value="LIKE">contains</option>
                <option value="NOT LIKE">does not contain</option>
                <option value="LIKE">begins with</option>
            </select>
        </td>


    </tr>
```

Comment: An tell us *what* reference is null...

Comment: `parent().parent().parent()` can be replaced by `.parents()` with the element you want as the parameter.

Comment: Instead of `parent().parent().parent()` use `.closest('div.some-selector')`

Comment: Also you could reduce a lot of this: e.g.
$option.parents( 'parent I'm looking for ').find('.criteria-value input').attr('id')

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a chain of `parent()` calls, try the `closest()` function.

```
$option.closest('div.parentClass').find('.criteria-value')....
```

Pass it a valid selector for whatever parent you're looking for. This way you don't rely on structure so much.